# How to modify the html file content in jsoup?

Tags: java, jsoup

I Have a html file like below

```
<div id ="test"> <u>s</u> </div>
```

I want to modify like this using java

```
  <div id ="test"> <b>Test<b> </div>
```

is it possible  in jsoup ?

Comment: Yes. http://jsoup.org/cookbook/modifying-data/set-html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it is posible:

```
  Element el = doc.select("div#test").first();
  for (Element elC : el.children()) {
      elC.remove();
  }
  Element nel = el.appendElement("b");
  nel.text("Test");
```